# What is the Pylons equivalent of Django's 'syncdb'?

Tags: pylons

Short and sweet question:

I've inherited a Pylons site with a bunch of models. If it was Django I would simply run 'syncdb' to set up a local database. What is the equivalent in Pylons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `paster setup-app development.ini` (replace `development.ini` with your actual configuration file).

This will go through your websetup.py file, which should create your tables if the project was started answering `True` to the question about using SQLAlchemy.